# Легко ли "затроллить" грамматика?

Tags: общие-вопросы

О ГРАММАТИКАХ
«Он раздражается, когда кто-то допускает грамматическую или орфографическую ошибку, и мгновенно бросается в атаку, размахивая словарями и ссылками на Грамоту.ру. Может быть ЛЕГКО ЗАТРОЛЛЕН, в результате чего потратит кучу времени на консультацию с академиком Виноградовым и Институтом русского языка РАН».

[Grammar nazi | Lurkmore](https://lurkmore.to/Grammar_nazi)

И всё-таки, можно ли затроллить грамматика и легко ли это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, всех подряд исправлять не стоит. Но если это твой знакомый или друг, то почему бы нет? И смотря как и для чего исправляешь. Можно культурно указать на ошибку, не завышая при этом себя, мол, смотрите, вы такие безграмотные, а я - грамотный. Я могу, например, исправить своих друзей. Пишут они - ужасно. Порой не поймешь о чем. Набор букв! Как не исправить! А набрасываться на всех и подряд - это, конечно, болезнь! Есть еще одно понятие. Не помню как называется. Распространено среди студентов-филологов (а может даже это и есть Граммар-наци). Известны случаи, когда они нападали на людей и зверски избивали их за ошибки.

Comment: Это уже нацизм! =)

Comment: Мне показалось интересным, как  не слишком грамотный человек может так затроллить грамматика, что тот, вместо достойного ответа неучу,  побежит справляться со словарями. У них какая-нибудь методика есть или это простое хвастовство? По-моему, это грамматики должны загонять своих противников в угол.

Comment: Если граммар-наци — вспыльчивый человек, то можно спокойно издеваться над этим человеком, да.

Comment: София, а что это за такой Граммар-наци,если он бежит справляться со словарем? Сам, наверное, неуч.

Comment: http://smixer.ru/news/a-181.html  Tagirix , я об этом говорил. См. ссылку.

Comment: Интересная информация, я просто под впечатлением. Умом Россию не понять, даже  грамотность у нас - это не просто грамотность. Наверное, тем важнее миссия просвещения и всестороннее изучение языка, если это может уменьшить напряженность в обществе. Давайте все будем стараться писать и говорить грамотно. Быть русским - значит уважать национальный язык, с этим трудно спорить.

Comment: @Серж, Ваша ссылка бесподобна! Зачетный троллинг!

Answer (score 9):

Попробовать что? Затроллить? Это не к нам, это к троллям. А споры были всегда и всегда будут. Может, это и хорошо. Все люди разные, у всех свои взгляды на жизнь, и все имеют право жить так, как они хотят - грамотными, не очень и допускающими много ошибок, но при этом не перестающими быть хорошими людьми. Среди моего общения есть много всяких. Я всех уважаю, если только кто-то не начинает кичиться своей грамотностью. Агрессию не выношу в любом виде, вот когда её вижу, появляется желание дать отпор, когда её нет - я очень терпима. Если человеку не так важна грамотность - что к нему приставать? Кто живёт наукой - им и флаг в руки, пусть "держат осаду", только истинно грамотный человек вряд ли за клинок схватится, ему это зачем? У нас толерантное общество, троллят те, кому делать нечего, вот и потешаются.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, Людмила.
Люди с ведущим правым полушарием просто не способны выучивать и применять на практике правила. Например, А. Ахматова всю жизнь писала с глупейшими ошибками.

Answer (score 5):

Как затроллить "граматика". Примерно как у Хармса:

> Писатель: Я писатель!
>   Читатель: А по-моему, ты *овно!
>   (Писатель стоит несколько минут, потрясённый этой новой идеей, и падает
>   замертво. Его выносят.)

Граммарнаци - это на любом форуме, кроме филологических и есть тролль, так как если человек не знает орфографии, это не означает, что он не разбирается ни в чём, а реакция на посты таких "грамматиков" уводит обсуждение от сути проблемы. Зачастую реагировать на грамотность человек начинает как раз тогда, когда спор по сути вопроса им явно проигрывается. Антитроллинг граммарнаци в основном как раз и строится на том, что человек прямо заявляет, что ему плевать на грамотность, главное, чтобы носители языка понимали, это если ответить ему считаете необходимым, ну, или универсальное "не корми тролля".

Если у объекта атаки граммарнаци есть желание ответить и развязать "священную войну" и самому его потроллить, то конкретные приёмы против данных лиц разнятся в зависимости от знаний сторон и степени "толщины" троллинга. Можно указать на ошибки в орфографии или по крайней мере пунктуации самого "наци" (на большинстве форумов стараются писать с соблюдением орфографии, но на пунктуации редко когда обращают внимание). Ещё часто указывают на то, что орфография это условность, у совсем "жирных" троллей этот посыл выражается в переходе на "йазыг падонкафф". Если подобные заявления идут в середине спора указывают на то, что оппонент этот спор проигрывает, раз переходи на проверку грамотности и пр.

В общем, не стоит лезть в чужой монастырь со своим Розенталем и указывать незнакомому человеку, что он что-то неправильно делает, если не уверены, что вас поймут правильно. Вы же не будете поправлять в реальной жизни подвыпившего грузчика, объясняя ему что слова "ложить" нет, так почему вы считаете возможным тоже самое делать в Сети?

Comment: Иногда без троллинга просто не обойтись, вот пример. Подходит к концу долгая, многодневная дискуссия о достоинствах русского языка, что непримиримо оспаривается оппонентом: "Пушкин, меж прочим, и на французском много писал. Просто в то время на французском писали все, кому не лень, а он предпочёл непаханное поле русского языка".- "Непаханый - одна буква Н". По-моему, неплохое троллинг-заключение, когда собеседник становится просто неинтересен. Так что порой случается хотя бы немного побыть граммарнаци.

Comment: А cлово "граммар-наци" через дефис же пишется. :)

Comment: >А cлово "граммар-наци" через дефис же пишется. :)

@Tagirix, это на каких основаниях? По-немецки слово писалось бы слитно, в русском языке нет ни слова "граммар", ни слова "наци", словарной фиксации у слова нет. Какие основания для чрездефисного написания?

Comment: Слово  ложить  используют  не  только  подвыпившие  грузчики,  но  и  огромное  количество  других  людей,  вполне  образованных.  Почитайте  комментарии  в  социальных  сетях.  Хотя  о  том,  что  такого  слова  нет,  пишущие  должны  были  узнать  ещё  в  школе.

Comment: У грузчиков "лОжить", у  более грамотных "ложИть" )))

Answer (score 3):

Можно.
Зачем?

> ' - Нельзя ли в горчицу подмешивать в джем?
>   ' - Пожалуйста. Можно. Но только зачем?
>   ' - А в собственной ванне держать бегемота?*)
>   ' - Да сколько угодно, была бы охота.
>   ' - А можно кота приводить на урок?
>   ' - Допустим, что да. Но какой в этом прок?
>   ' - А по морю плавать в дырявом корыте?
>   ' - Была бы охота, хоть в сите плывите!
>   ' - А можно кроить из железа пальто?
>   ' - Кроите, кроите! А дальше то что?
>   ' - А можно варить колбасу из каната?
>   ' - Ещё и не то можно делать, ребята:
>   ' в спортивный костюм наряжать индюка,
>   ' лопатой над крышей гонять облака,
>   ' себя самого вызывать к телефону,
>   ' учить щебетать пожилую ворону,
>   ' лягушку водить по бульвару в узде,
>   ' и вилами письма писать на воде,
>   ' и строить себе перед зеркалом рожи, 
>   ' всё это, друзья, разрешается тоже.
>   ' А можно ещё (для того - голова) - 
>   ' "Зачем это нужно?" - подумать сперва.

==========
перевод, кажется с польского.
Автора не знаю

*)привет!

Comment: Зачем троллить грамматика? Чтобы он не указывал Вам на ошибки в качестве последнего довода для доказательства своей правоты.  А вот как это сделать (без применения силового воздействия, в рамках конкретной форумной площадки) - это вопрос. Вы знаете ответ?

Answer (score 2):

За много лет у меня выработалась привычка никогда не делать замечания о неправильно произнесенном или употребленном слове или фразе. Это относится к членам моей семьи, к друзьям, знакомым, коллегам. Просто я, заметив ошибку, стараюсь в ближайшие секунды разговора вставить в свое высказывание такое же слово, но произнесенное и употребленное верно. Умный собеседник это понимает и с благодарностью воспринимает мой деликатный ход. А глупому бесполезно что-то исправлять.

Comment: >> Просто я, заметив ошибку, стараюсь в ближайшие секунды разговора вставить в свое высказывание такое же слово, но произнесенное и употребленное верно. Умный собеседник это понимает и с благодарностью воспринимает мой деликатный ход.

Ничего себе деликатный... Собеседник достает кошелек и пересчитывает в нем мелочь, и тут вы в ближайшие секунды достаете бумажник и деликатно начинаете шуршать купюрами. Собеседник аж прослезится от благодарности...

Comment: Деликатный человек не пересчитывает деньги (ни мелочь, ни купюры) в присутствии собеседника.  
Если, конечно, он не собирается попросить милостыню.

Comment: >За много лет у меня выработалась привычка никогда не делать замечания о неправильно произнесенном или употребленном слове или фразе. 

*...Воробьёв... знал, что сработает отточенная годами привычка, и ровно через десять часов он проснется...*

>Просто я, заметив ошибку, стараюсь в ближайшие секунды разговора вставить в свое высказывание такое же слово, но произнесенное и употребленное верно.

А я, заметив у кого-то ошибку на этом форуме, стараюсь в ближайшие секунды открыть вопрос, имеющий своей целью установить истину, неучу неизвестную.

Comment: >Умный собеседник это понимает и с благодарностью воспринимает мой деликатный ход.  

Интеллигентный человек тут же застрелится...

>А глупому бесполезно что-то исправлять.

А неинтеллигентный... по крайней мере, не вступит с вами в открытый конфликт ― и то ладно.

Comment: Да ладно вам, что вы все на Виктора накинулись? Мне, например, гораздо больше нравится когда собеседник поступает именно так, как описал Виктор. Гладко, незаметно, и тактично. Если есть какая-то разница в произношении, ударении, и т.д., я примечу, а потом сама посмотрю в словаре, кто же из нас прав. Не надо человека тыкать носом в мелкие ошибки - те, кто внимательно слушают, и так заметят и поймут.

Answer (score 0):

София, зачем Вы читаете Лукоморье? Конечно же, мне этот сайт тоже нравится. Вчера мы с другом, встретившись, много смеялись над написанной статью о Григории Перельмане (см. [Григорий Перельман | Lurkmore](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD) ).

Лукоморье — сайт, предназначенный для поднятия настроения. А вот понятие «граммар-наци» мне знакомо. Я даже знаю некоторых таких личностей. Как Вы и сказали, они действительно стараются править ошибки, находимые ими в сети. Мне как-то раз кто-то сказал: «Не нужно исправлять людей, даже если ты корректор».

Корректор, как человек, исправляющий ошибки — да и не только ошибки —, всегда очень внимателен к тексту. Даже если мой друг совершает ошибку в сообщении, я стараюсь игнорировать это. Граммар-наци же обычно пишут в открытую о совершённой кем-то ошибке.

Кажется, я что-то не по теме.

Постскриптум. Видели нашего фюрера на Лукоморье? ;)

Comment: Я случайно попала на этот сайт, он упоминался в "Большом вопросе".

Comment: Непрофессиональная, думаю, статья о Перельмане, раз там есть ссылка на Иртеньева, а нет ссылки на [Каганова](http://f5.ru/kaganov/post/215761)

Answer (score 0):

Мне нравятся взгляды Максима Кронгауза на граммар-наци и на лингвистическое высокомерие:

[«В обществе развито лингвистическое высокомерие»
(Максим Кронгауз о пуристах, радующихся чужим ошибкам) | Московские новости](http://www.mn.ru/society_edu/20120902/326319711.html)

Comment: Воинствующая грамотность и воинствующая неграмотность: можно подумать, что грамотная речь - это только предлог для противостояния. Наверное, не надо делать замечания людям, которые вас об это не просят. Но наверное, с такими людьми надо говорить на подчеркнуто  грамотном и выразительном языке, чтобы они чувствовали разницу. Это все равно как изысканная вежливость по отношению к грубияну.

Comment: Не согласен. С ними надо говорить на том языке, на котором вы привыкли говорить всегда. Зачем на подчеркнуто? Зачем чтобы они чувствовали разницу? Представьте, что вы разговариваете с иностранцем на его языке, а он подчеркнуто будет говорить СЛОЖНО. Чтобы вы почувствовали разницу.

Comment: Ну хорошо, не подчеркивайте, но в такой ситуации сами старайтесь выражаться грамотно, внимательно следите за своей речью и письмом. Тогда ваш язык будет служить образцом для заблудшей неграмотной овечки.

Comment: @София, воинствующая неграмотность по Кронгазу - это нарочитое письмо с ошибками, вроде "йазыка падонкафф". Кронгауз считает, что появился такой язык из-за того, что раньше писали только те кто умел писать грамотно, а сейчас пишут все. Чтобы преодолеть психологический барьер от того, что пишешь неграмотно и появились подобные нарочитые ошибки, причём это явление наблюдалось не только в русском языке. Сейчас писать таким образом в рунете уже считается неприличным.

Comment: Неужели Кронгауз на самом деле так считает? Психологический барьер от того, что пишешь неграмотно?

Я встречал мнение, что "йазык падонкафф" придумали вполне грамотные люди и пишут (писали) на нем тоже люди вполне грамотные. Да и по собственному опыту знаю. ))

Comment: @Niemand

>И.МАКСУТОВ: Я бы... только не неграмотность массы не полагался... внутри должна быть какая-то... причина, помимо простого желания спрятать свою неграмотность.   
М.КРОНГАУЗ: Причин было несколько, конечно. Была причине ещё очень важная — протестная. Это был такой протест: мы в интернете другие... Если я свободный человек, то я могу писать неправильно — вот в чём был принцип... Тут сложились разные факторы, но один из важных факторов, почему это легло на душу массам, потому что это действительно замечательно уводило из критики. 

http://www.rusnovosti.ru/guests/visitor/42931/257728/

Comment: В  олбанском  языке  тоже  свои  нормы.  Там  тоже  не  абы  как.

Answer (score 0):

Слушайте, а есть у вас какой-нибудь знакомый грамматический нацист? Познакомьте меня! Я всю жизнь такого искала, но кругом одни интеллигенты – и безграмотность – и в первую очередь моя – цветет и благоухает.

> Это всё сказки и страшилки. На самом деле нет Деда Мороза, Бабы-Яги, и Граммарнаци тоже нет.

*– А дьявола тоже нет? – вдруг весело осведомился больной у Ивана Николаевича.*

*– И дьявола...*

*– Не противоречь! – одними губами шепнул Берлиоз, обрушиваясь за спину профессора и гримасничая.*

*– Нету никакого дьявола! – растерявшись от всей этой муры, вскричал Иван Николаевич не то, что нужно, – вот наказание! Перестаньте вы психовать.*

*Тут безумный расхохотался так, что из липы над головами сидящих выпорхнул воробей.*

*– Ну, уж это положительно интересно, – трясясь от хохота проговорил профессор, – что же это у вас, чего ни хватишься, ничего нет! – он перестал хохотать внезапно и, что вполне понятно при душевной болезни, после хохота впал в другую крайность – раздражился и крикнул сурово: – Так, стало быть, так-таки и нету?*

И вот еще что я хочу сказать вам, господа присутствующие, а в особенности – те, кто сейчас во цвете юности.

В бытность мою слушателем школьного курса, моя преданность идеалам лингвистического фашизма принимала формы столь исступленного фанатизма, что я принималась поправлять нашего учителя русского языка! А он со мной соглашался (!!!) Как всякий человек, который, когда его перебивают, пытаясь закончить фразу, говорит: «Вы извините, что перебиваю…» В результате я добилась того, что теперь этот несчастный учитель, а вместе с тем — единственный дорогой мне человек, ни знать, ни видеть меня не хочет. Трусами нас делает раздумье, а неспособность думать – обладателями искалеченной судьбы.

Теперь совет тем, кто вплотную подошел к тому моменту, когда обломствовать далее нет более возможности и необходимо определиться с предназначением. Если вы интеллигентный человек — я вас заклинаю: не становитесь учителем. Стараниями подобных мне, нахальных, бестактных, умствующих честолюбцев, ваше педагогическое образование трансформируется в онкологическое.

P. S. Да, учитель, о котором шла речь выше, убедил приемную комиссию оценить мою экзаменационную работу высшим баллом, хотя я сделала три ошибки в изложении, преследуя цель остаться на второй год (я была уверена, что мы с ним еще не все обсудили). «Поставьте ей десять, — убеждал он, — я этого не выдержу».

Comment: Это всё сказки и страшилки. На самом деле нет Деда Мороза, Бабы-Яги, и Граммарнаци тоже нет.

Comment: Дед  Мороз  есть !

Comment: А Баба-Яга - и подавно!

Comment: Нету никого (© Аукцыон)

Answer (score 0):

Намеренное искажение грамматики можно использовать в качестве эффективного ничем другим не заменяемого литературного приёма. Например, неправильная расстановка запятых может передавать динамику речи пьяного, безумца или гения в припадке вдохновения, или просто накладывать на фразу интересный ритм, несущий дополнительную смысловую нагрузку.

(От конкретных примеров воздержусь, можно найти кучу у, например, обэриутов)

Такие приёмы, думаю, наиболее эффективны для укрощения грамотеев. Те из них, которые не врубаются, будут посрамлены как не врубающиеся, а которые врубаются тем придётся промолчать.