# Как стать граммар-наци?

Tags: другое

На фоне недавно опубликованного поста хотел бы узнать, как же все ж таки стать граммар-наци. Давайте вообще пообсуждаем такое вот "звание".

Comment: Уже обсуждалось. http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/25301/общие-вопросы-кто-такие-граммарнаци

Если хотите стать граммарнаци достаточно лишь к месту и без поправлять написанное людьми. Подойдёт любой форум кроме лингвистических.

Comment: Вопрос какой-то безынтересный. Там не написано, как получить эдакое звание.

Comment: А зачем?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вопрос какой-то безынтересный. Там не написано, как получить эдакое звание.

Гораздо интереснее вопрос, как от этого звания избавиться. Феномен лингвистического терроризма возник как следствие исключительно положительного стремления — стремления к совершенству. Однако в глазах общественности это явление имеет негативный характер, поскольку воспринимается как стремление продемонстрировать свое превосходство. Впрочем, не мне судить, — возможно, в ряде случаев именно это стремление лежит в основе лингвотерроризма. Как бы то ни было, нельзя недооценивать важность необходимости подчинить контролю стремление привести все в мире в соответствие с собственными и общепринятыми представлениями о совершенстве. О том, насколько это важно, подробнее, убедительнее и драматичнее [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36784/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=37326#37326).

Answer (score 1):

Есть люди неученые, ученые и переученные. 
Последние как раз и становятся граммарнаци. Они, будучи не слишком богато одарёнными в интеллектуальном плане, часто тщеславны и при этом очень упорны и усидчивы. Напихивают в свою (не слишком ёмкую) голову избыток информации, а впоследствии она, не переваренная, не претворённая в знания, изливается на всех, кто не успел спрятаться.

Учение - свет только при условии умственной одарённости. Иначе оно хуже тьмы...

Answer (score 0):

Это - увы! -  враждебно!  Заложено в человеке.Обычно это  филологи,лингвисты.

Comment: Не соглашусь. Можно быть эдаким без наличия филологического образования.

Comment: Без филологического образования вряд ли у вас хватят знания все и всех исправлять!

Comment: Я часто встречаю таких людей, у которых нет филологического образования.

Comment: >Без филологического образования вряд ли у вас хватят знания все и всех исправлять!

Для возникновения желания все и всех исправлять абсолютная грамотность не требуется — достаточно знать что-то, чего не знает некто.